# SSRS Issue: Rounding to nearest .25

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS (2008) report that takes in a raw transactions, then groups and totals them. At the "Total" level, I would like to round the final numbers to the nearest .25, however I cannot find a method to do this. According to what I've read, the Round() function in SSRS only rounds to integers. I have found a couple ways to do it in SQL, but the problem is, I want to do all the calculations with the REAL numbers and just round the result so that I don't introduce a significant amount of error from the real numbers. Here's the best SQL solution I could find:

```
dec(round(number * 4, 0)/4,11,2) as Nearest_Qtr
```

Anyone know how I could do the equivalent in the actual SSRS report?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function on the Report code:

```
Function MyRound(dblFigure As Double, dblMultiplier As Double) As Double
    MyRound = Round(dblFigure / dblMultiplier, 0) * dblMultiplier
End Function
```

And then call it on your report:

```
=Code.MyRound(value, 0.25)
```

Comment: Beautiful and elegant! That allows me to round to whatever number or fraction I need!! Perfect!

Comment: Is it possible to make this function always round *up*, like with Ceiling?

Comment: Exactly the same but always round up? I can't test it right now, but I guess you will have to change the MyRound function to `Round(Ceiling(...),0)`